# Single address wallets - no change addresses

Tags: address, change

Is it legal for Bitcoin transaction to spend output back to one of the input addresses? Namely, to create a single address wallet (paper wallet), so that change addresses do not need to be generated.

Looks like all popular wallets create change addresses for privacy reasons, but I'd like to know if this is also a limitation of protocol. Also asking this question separately from deterministic address generation.